# MySQL: Is there a way to replace part of a column value based on a value in another table (in a single query)

Tags: mysql

Here is the thing:
I got a column as such:

```
table1
ID  Name  Playlist
1   Hi     Category1|Category2|Category3
2   Ho     Category2|Category4|Category6
etc...
```

Then another table:

```
table2
ID Name
1 Category1
2 Category2
3 Category3
....
```

On table one, the value string is really "Category1|Category2|Category3".
I would like a single query to replace all strings in the playlist column of table1 with their respective IDs from table2, so that after the query, table1 should look like this:

```
table1
ID  Name  Playlist
1   Hi     1|2|3
2   Ho     2|4|6
etc...
```

I can do this by programming a loop or something of the sort, but I would like to have it in a single query, however, I have no idea how specifically replace part of the value of the column with different values.

If it was just:

```
table1
    ID  Name  Playlist
    1   Hi     Category1
    2   Ho     Category2
    etc...
```

I would then use the query like:

```
UPDATE table1 a, table b SET a.playlist = b.Name WHERE a.`Playlists` = b.`Name`;
```

Although i really want the requested query for this, I still would like to hear suggestions for a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm,I think it's less difficult than you can imagine. Try this queries :
1.To see, is the result you intend to get?:

```
SELECT playlist,REPLACE(playlist,'category','')AS MyResult FROM table1;
```

2.If 'Myresult' of the query,mentioned above, is what you want then just update your table:

```
UPDATE table1 SET playlist=REPLACE(playlist,'category','');
```